# Remove McAfee branding from Windows login

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, disk-encryption, mcafee

McAfee Enterprise plasters its brand over everything on the PC. **Everything**.

The latest is that since installing disk encryption, the McAfee logo is placed *over* the user account picture on the Windows 7 login screen.

Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: Don't use crappy products that abuse their power.

Comment: Do you have any screenshots of this? I've never seen what you're describing.

Comment: @EEAA I wouldn't touch McAfee with a pole on my personal PC, but I don't get to choose security products for my work PC.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'd love to do that, but you can't actually do a screen capture on the login page. PrtScn does nothing, which I'm sure is for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To add/change pictures, you need to go to Menu - > Configuration - > server settings -> endpoint encryption -> mange themes.

To change it in the policies configured, you need to go to Policies Catalog, at product type choose Endpoint Encryption x.x.x, Category: Product Settings and click on the policy. Go to Theme tab and on that screen you have the option to change the the picture